# Pandas: How can I preserve row ordering after subtraction?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subtraction

I have two data frames with three columns, with identical column names. I want to subtract the value of the third column where the values of the first, and second columns match. I've tried the following:

```py
# Common column names
columns = ["month", "category", "sum"]

# First data frame
data1 = [("jan", "j", 10), ("feb", "f", 20)]
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data1, columns=columns)

# Second data frame
data2 = [("jan", "j", 9.5), ("mar", "m", 30)]
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data2, columns=columns)

print(df1)  # Observe order of `month`s: jan, feb
print(df2)  # Observe order of `month`s: jan, mar

# Subtract `sum` where `month`, and `category` match:
df1.set_index(["month", "category"]).subtract(df2.set_index(["month", "category"])).reset_index()
```

This yields the following output.
Observe that rows are sorted alphabetically on `month`.

```
  month category  sum
0   feb        f  NaN
1   jan        j  0.5
2   mar        m  NaN
```

How can I maintain the row order of the left hand operand? I.e. how can get the following output (or similar):

```
  month category  sum
1   jan        j  0.5
0   feb        f  NaN
2   mar        m  NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.merge` will preserve the order of the left operand, then you can calculate the difference between two columns. You can do this for example:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["month", "category"], how="outer")
df3.loc[:, "difference"] = df3["sum_x"] - df3["sum_y"]
```

Which yields on your data:

```
  month category  sum_x  sum_y  difference
0   jan        j   10.0    9.5         0.5
1   feb        f   20.0    NaN         NaN
2   mar        m    NaN   30.0         NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the columns categorical and specify any order you seem fit:

```
df1['month'] = pd.Categorical(df1['month'], categories=['jan', 'feb', 'mar'], ordered=True)
df2['month'] = pd.Categorical(df2['month'], categories=['jan', 'feb', 'mar'], ordered=True)

# Subtract `sum` where `month`, and `category` match:
res = df1.set_index(["month", "category"]).subtract(df2.set_index(["month", "category"])).reset_index()
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
  month category  sum
0   jan        j  0.5
1   feb        f  NaN
2   mar        m  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
df1.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

This just forces the dataframe to be sorted as per index.
More documentation found here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Since `pandas` version 1.1.0 [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) can take a parameter `key`. You could pass a desired order with that parameter:

```
order = {"jan": 0, "feb": 1, "mar": 2}
df1.set_index(["month", "category"]).subtract(df2.set_index(["month", "category"])).reset_index().sort_values(by=['month'], key=lambda x: x.map(order))
```

**Output:**

```
    month   category    sum
1     jan          j    0.5
0     feb          f    NaN
2     mar          m    NaN
```